# Remember loaded elements with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a full AJAX website. On a page with **12 elements** and a homemade infinite scroll (just a "more" link at the bottom of the page, loading the 12 next elements), when I click on one of these links, it loads the page.

### The problem

When I want to come back to the list (browser's previous or close link) and **if I loaded more than 12 photos** (all, for example), I lose the loaded elements and I need to scroll to the bottom of the page… load another elements… click on it… load the page… go back, etc.

Do you know what can I do to avoid this behavior and keep the loaded elements progression?

### My test

I tested something. I define a variable with the base loaded elements and I compare it with the new loaded elements, then it runs something if the `last` value is higher than the new one.

```
last = $(".grid.photos article").length;

var newelems = $(data).find(".grid.photos article").length,
    perpage = 12,
    diff = last - newelems;

if (last > newelems){
    var times = Math.ceil(diff / perpage);
    // DO SOMETHING MAGIC
}
```

Comment: That's the default behavior of the page if you want to retain a certain information in the page even closing the browser, you can use cookies

Comment: You can use cookies or [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

Comment: I thought to do a click's trigger as many time as necessary (via the variable `times`) to reload elements and keep the position but I don't know if it's a good solution…

Comment: Note that you have a size limit using cookies or local/session storage. If your whole site uses AJAX, how about you load clicked items in a modal window without reloading the page? If so, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page). Also make sure to let your users access those individual pages with regular links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution (working!) which plays with a parameter in the url.

### PHP (Wordpress)

```
$perpage = ($_GET["last"]) ? $_GET["last"] : 6;

...

"posts_per_page" => $perpage
```

### jQuery

```
// Set last position for photos list
last = $(".grid.photos article").length;

// Retrieve the position
if (last > 6)
    url += "?last=" + last;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding hash to the location so there is an actual url associated with each state.  For example

```
 window.location.hash = 'load12';
```

then you could build logic off of that hash to see what needs to be loaded.  Another idea is to work with HTML5 [pushState](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).